# How can I add looping per 250 cells and offset the array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that looks at column A and loops through to create an array to paste to another destination, but I want to manipulate it to loop through sets of 250 cells and create a concatenated array and print it to cells B1. After that set of 250, I go cells a251-a501, and so forth until I reach the end of the list and have each set of 250 concatenated ID's (separated by a ";") to print to the next destination row (B1>B2>B3, etc..)

```
Sub JC_Fill()

Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim x As Long, i As Long

i = 0
x = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ReDim varArray(1)                        'resize array

    Do Until Cells(x, 1).Value = ""

        If Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then
            varArray(i) = Cells(x, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve varArray(i)
        End If

        x = x + 1
    Loop



    ReDim Preserve varArray(i - 1)

End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = varArray



End Sub
```

How could I edit my `Do While/Loop` to repeat the process every 250 cells and then concatenate the array to one cell separated by `;` and then offset the next batch until I have no more ID's to cycle through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code this way:

```
Sub JC_Fill()

Dim OutString
Dim x As Long, i As Long

Dim out_row As Long

i = 0
x = 1
out_row = 1


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    OutString = ""

    Do Until Cells(x, 1).Value = ""

        If Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then
            If (x > 1) Then OutString = OutString & ";"
            OutString = OutString & Cells(x, 1).Value
        End If


        If (x Mod 250) = 0 Then
          ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & out_row).Value = OutString
          OutString = ""
          out_row = out_row + 1
        End If

        x = x + 1

    Loop

End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & out_row).Value = OutString



End Sub
```

Comment: `varArray(i) = Cells(x, 1).Value` so it gets to this line (row 250) but 249 in the array index and gives me a `subscript out of range` error. I can see it's got all 250 Id's stored in the array, but it doesn't get to the printing of the array

Comment: Do you need to use an array to store the values or it's possible to use a string? It would be way faster. If it's possible, I'll change the code

Comment: I feel like a string would work, right? I just need it to store the 250 ID's separated by a `;` and then print it to the destination cell. and then loop the next batch of ID's /offset the destination cell by +1

Comment: Of course, it'll work! Ok, let's do it, then, give me a minute :)

Comment: Glad it helped, have a nice day!

Comment: whoops, I didn't know you couldn't accept both that were given, just changed it back

Answer (score 1):

For interest, you can do this without looping each of the 250 cells.

```
Sub x()

Dim n As Long, v As Variant, r As Range, n2 As Long

n = 5 '250 for you
n2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set r = Range("A1").Resize(n)
Do While Len(r(1)) > 0
    If n2 - r(1).Row < n Then Set r = r.Resize(n2 - r(1).Row + 1)
    If r.Count = 1 Then
        v = r.Value
    Else
        v = Join(Application.Transpose(r), ";")
    End If
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = v
    Set r = r.Offset(n)
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I learned something new: v = Join(Application.Transpose(r), ";")! THANKS